# Playing successive tracks on Soundcloud

Tags: soundcloud

I currently allow users to log in through Soundcloud and I created a list of track ID's of their music.

With this data, I created an array of all the track ID and randomized it. How can I go about playing these songs? This works for individual tracks:

```
SC.stream("/tracks/###", function(sound){
    sound.play();
});
```

But how can I get a notice for when the song ends so I can begin a new track?

**update:**

I could record the duration of the song and setTimeout the stopping and playing of a new track but maybe there is a more Soundcloud way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onfinish method

```
SC.stream("/tracks/###", 
{onfinish: function(){ alert('track finished');}}, 
function(sound){sound.play();
});
```

Here is another thread around the same issue.

[How can I automatically move to next sound after previous track completes using the Soundcloud Javascript SDK for streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635323/how-can-i-automatically-move-to-next-sound-after-previous-track-completes-using/17639636)

Comment: Thanks! If anyone else is interested, it looks like onfinish is an option as part of the soundManager2 sound object and the main page for that is here http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/