# Does soundobjects delete when finished?

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

When I use SC.stream to stream a track, does the track streamed data get automatically deleted once it is finished and I play another track? The thing is that when I called SC.stream before it was finished I got 2 tracks playing at the same time. This means that they do not override atleast. Does anyone have further knowledge of this? Do I have to make a onFinish function to the sound that deletes itself using the soundobjects function?

To summarize: Do I need to dispose of the sound manually when using SC.stream and can I call on multiple SC.stream?

EDIT:
As response to a request for code

```
SC.callMethod('stream',["/tracks/" + content.split(":")[0], new JsObject.jsify({"autoLoad": true, "autoPlay": true, "stream": true, "position": int.parse(content.split(":")[1])})]);
```

and that makes probably 0 sense to anyone as that is dart and is server dependent. I will instead explain it. I call SC.stream feeding a track as the first parameter. The second parameter is the options with the settings

> autoLoad: true, autoPlay: true, stream: true

and a position. The thing is I am currently calling SC.stream every time I am changing track, using my own timer. I do also not feed a function(sound) to save the sound reference.

Comment: Pls share some code. Looks like that your code creates 2 or more objects and they will exist until you destory them. Onfinish method could be one option to change the actual sound - or stop all existing streams when a new one starts. This thread may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635323/how-can-i-automatically-move-to-next-sound-after-previous-track-completes-using/17639636

Comment: I added the code but mainly just explained it as my code out of place makes 0 sense.

Comment: As i said, looks like you create everytime a new js-object. Afaik SC.stream creates an underlying sm2-obj. Therefore i'd recommend to destroy all existing objects by calling the mentioned method.

Comment: Ok then :) I guess that is the answer I wanted for the question I asked. Thanks.